# In Javascript (when using node.js), how do you know/define the scope of variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I define something in a passed function, e.g.

`var name = "Whatever";`

Is this now accessible from other parts of the application, or is it limited? What's the logic behind defining scope in node.js javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable defined in a method is only available in that method, if you use `var`.  If you do

`myVar = 1;`

myVar will be global.

Node is like other javascript.  Node does define a `global` variable, so you can do things like

`global.SOME_CONSTANT = 'A Constant'`

and then use that like

`SOME_CONSTANT`

anywhere in your code/modules.

Because node is asynchronous, you end up defining a lot of callbacks. i.e. you do a lot of

```
someModule.someMethod(opts, function(data){
   // callback code in here
});
```

where the function you passed in gets invoked by `someMethod` when it is done.  Let's say you invoked `someModule.someMethod` in a function.  If you defined a variable in that outer function, so your code looks like

```
var x = [];
someModule.someMethod(opts, function(data){
   // x is available in this callback because of closures, so you can do
   x.push(data);
});
```

the variable defined in the outer scope is available in the callback because of closures.  I suggest you spend some time reading about closures in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` variable will only be available in the function in which it was created, or in the functions nested *inside* that function.

This is true irrespective of where the function is passed. It's *original variable environment* is carried along with it wherever it goes, and any code *outside* that environment will not have access to `name`.

Answer (score 1):

It´s only available in the module, and only in the function it is defined.
There´s no way to define the scope. Every module has its own global scope.

You should read about closures ;)